# How do I change flutter web icon image and description on google search?

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter_web, I tried to change the icon and web description in google search results. I tried to use flutter_launcher_icons and edit  manifest.json, but there is no change in the google search result, any ideas?
[image]

manifest.json

[image]